# How to call Tab of particular activity from other activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have created two tabs.Tab A and Tab B. From Tab A, i am navigating to new activity say C. From C how to navigate to Tab A of particular activity. When i tried, it's opening new activity and I can't call which is present inside the tab.Please help me.

```
public class TabsActivity extends TabActivity {
String Activity;
Intent i;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs);


    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Photos
    TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab A");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    photospec.setIndicator("Tab A");
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

    // Tab for Songs

    TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab B");        
    songspec.setIndicator("Tab B");

    Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

    // Tab for Videos


    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
    tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab

}
```

In A activity using button, i am moving to another activity..say for eg: NewActivity

In NewActivity, how to switch back to A which is present inside Tabs.

NewActivity.java

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,
         listsearchbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listfilter);
        listsearchbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                        TabsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Activity", "A");
            //i dont know where to use getIntent in TabsActivity to call A activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Activityname.this.finish();` on button click

Comment: without using finish any idea how to do it?